# Get filename and move files in AWS S3 using Mule

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, mule, polling, anypoint-studio

I have 3 S3 buckets:

1. input-files
2. in-progress
3. processed-files

The "input-files" bucket contains a list of CSV files and I want to get each input file (filename format: filename-timestamp) from the bucket one at a time and move it to the "in-progress" bucket and when the workflow is complete I want to move it to "processed-files" bucket.  On error all file processing needs to stop.

In my flow I can get the content of the csv file but there is no reference to file name so not sure how I can implement the above because I can't specify the file that needs to be moved.

How can I implement the processing steps outlined above?

XML flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.8.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">

    <flow name="CsvToMongo" >
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <s3:get-object-content config-ref="Amazon_S3__Configuration" bucketName="test-file-bucket" key="input-files/TestData.csv" mimeType="application/csv" doc:name="Amazon S3"/>
        </poll>
        <object-to-string-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/csv" doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <logger message="#['**** Start writing CSV to database...']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger: Start Process"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Software being used:
Anypoint Studio 6.2
Mule 3.8.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An approach that I used recently was to configure an [Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)](https://aws.amazon.com/de/sqs/) queue to receive S3 events from a bucket. (Configure the bucket to send events to the SQS queue).

Then in my Mule flow, my input source is an [SQS poller](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/amazon-sqs-connector).

The structure of the [S3 event is well documented at AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) and is a JSON string ([convert it to JSON object to use it](https://dzone.com/articles/payload-transformation-json-to-object)) and contains all the relevant information that I needed to identify the actual file name.

It's working quite nicely.